# Accessing elements in the dictionary of python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a simple code below. I want to access "RTYM9 Index" and 1593.3

```
d= {
  "schema": {
    "type": "string",
    "optional": false
  },
  "payload": "{\"subscriptionId\":\"//blp/mktdata/RTYM9 Index?fields=LAST_PRICE\",\"MarketDataEvents\":{\"LAST_PRICE\":1593.3}}"
}
```

I have tried below code.

```
f=d['payload']

print(' "Bloomber Data" : ', json_data_f.split("mktdata/")[1].split("?")[0])
print(' "Price" : ', f.split("LAST_PRICE")[2])
```

Desired Output --

```
{"Bloomberg Data" : 'RTYM9 Index',
"Price" : 159.3}
```

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: I am new to stack overflow and don't know to how format code. Do let me know and also help in getting my answer.

Comment: If you do not know about python, you should begin by learning the basics at least, for example on https://realpython.com/

Comment: Please explain, what have I asked wrong ? except formatting of coding.

Comment: You should give us the code you tried so far... Look at these: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Now I mention, what I have tried. If you have my answer, then do reply.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 uses upper case for `False`, also `json_data_f` is not defined, it should be `f`

```
d= {
  "schema": {
    "type": "string",
    "optional": False
  },
  "payload": "{\"subscriptionId\":\"//blp/mktdata/RTYM9 Index?fields=LAST_PRICE\",\"MarketDataEvents\":{\"LAST_PRICE\":1593.3}}"
}

f=d['payload']

print(' "Bloomber Data" : ', f.split("mktdata/")[1].split("?")[0])
print(' "Price" : ', f.split("LAST_PRICE")[2])
```

Gives:

```
 "Bloomber Data" :  RTYM9 Index
 "Price" :  ":1593.3}}
```

You can trim any excess fuff around your values with `str.strip()`

Answer (score 0):

[Regex](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html) are designed for such jobs, here is an example:

```
import re

b = re.search("mktdata\/(.+)\?", f=d['payload'])

print(b.group(1))  # >>> Output: "RTYM9 Index"
```

> There are many websites where you can learn about regex and practice, like this one: https://regexr.com/